# Saving with core data

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

I am newbie to programming currently. Im trying to save a core data object but at the moment I have a error with saving the Coredata with displaying the error. Focussing on the save function.

)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  HitList
//
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    //Change “names” to “people” and [String] to [NSManagedObject]
    var people = [NSManagedObject]()

    @IBAction func addName(sender: AnyObject) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Name", message: "Add a new name", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save",
            style: .Default,
            handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in

                let textField = alert.textFields!.first
                self.saveName(textField!.text!)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
        })

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default) {
            (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        }

        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
            (textField: UITextField) -> Void in
        }

        alert.addAction(saveAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)

        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "\"The List\""
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    // MARK: UITableViewDataSource
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return people.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        cellForRowAtIndexPath
        indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell =
            tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")

            let person = people[indexPath.row]

            cell!.textLabel!.text =
                person.valueForKey("name") as? String

            return cell!
    }

    func saveName(name: String) {
        //1
        let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

        //2
        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person",
            inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

        let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
            insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        //3
        person.setValue(name, forKey: "name")

        //4
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            //5
            people.append(person)
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8089631d50'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d6dde65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f41ddeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d6e648d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d63390a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d6334b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d5ad652 CFStringCreateCopy + 242
    6   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000010f9d52d8 _TTSf4g_d___TFSSCfMSSFT12_cocoaStringPSs9AnyObject__SS + 104
    7   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000010f99c9c3 _TFSSCfMSSFT12_cocoaStringPSs9AnyObject__SS + 19
    8   libswiftFoundation.dylib            0x000000010fd6e260 _TF10Foundation24_convertNSStringToStringFGSqCSo8NSString_SS + 16
    9   Gill                                0x000000010d168486 _TToFC4Gill14ViewController8saveNamefS0_FSST_ + 54
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010defc194 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010e06b6fc -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010e06b9c8 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010e06aaf8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010df6b49b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010df6c1d0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010df1ab66 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010def4d97 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6844
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d609a31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d5ff95c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d5fee13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d5fe828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000111d1dad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010defa610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    24  Gill                                0x000000010d16b2ad main + 109
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010ff2f92d start + 1
    26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Can you show the NSException that's printed out? Which line does it crash on?

Comment: it crashes on - class app delegate
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

Comment: It appears that it's crashing with the "unrecognized selector sent to instance" for a UIButton, and may not have anything to do with your Core Data. Could you provide some more context around what you're doing to get the error, and if your buttons are set up properly?